# Tabulator: how to reload multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, dom, tabulator

I browsed Tabulator topics here, but didn't find anything similar to what I'm trying to achieve. Namely, my project generates multiple Tabulator tables from one big array. I am trying to implement a feature to manually add a new table, but having issues with one thing: how to reload all the tables with the newly added table. The problem is that it seems to generate extra ones without removing the previously loaded tables. Perhaps I am missing one line removing all the previous tables?

(problem pictured below, you can see the "empty" tables, while only the one with content should have been appended)
[image]

[Here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/abzRejp?editors=1111) is a codepen to play around with. You can replicate the problem by entering gibberish to the input fields (both sides) and clicking "Add dictionary" My code essentially loops through all the nested arrays from the tabledata array and creates a separate table for each one.

Thanks for anyone taking a look and thinking along!

Here's the table-generating loop:

```
const drawTables = () => {

for (let dictionary = 0; dictionary < tabledata.length; dictionary++) {

  let table = new Tabulator(("#dictionary-" + dictionary), {
    data: tabledata[dictionary],
    layout: "fitColumns",
    reactiveData: true,
    // headerSort: false,
    layoutColumnsOnNewData: true,

    columns: [ //define the table columns
      {
        title: "domain",
        field: "domain",
        editor: "input",
        validator: "unique"
      },
      {
        title: "range",
        field: "range",
        editor: "input",
        validator: "unique"
      }
    ],
  });
}

}
```

And here's the attempt to create a new table and inject it to the big tabledata array

```
//event listener for form entry
let addDictionaryForm = document.querySelector("#add-dictionary-form")
addDictionaryForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addDictionary();
})


const addDictionary = () => {
  let newDictionary = []
  let domainInput = document.querySelectorAll(".domainInput");
  let rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".rangeInput");
  let rangeIdx = 0;

  //looping through form entries and adding them to the newDictionary array only if both fields are filled out
  for (let i = 0; i < domainInput.length; i++) {
    if (domainInput[i].value && rangeInput[rangeIdx].value) {
      newDictionary.push({
        domain: domainInput[i].value,
        range: rangeInput[rangeIdx].value
      });
    }
    rangeIdx++;

  }

//add form entries to the general dictionary array
  tabledata.unshift(newDictionary)

// refresh table?
drawTables();
tabledata.setData();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you define an array of tables, lets say we call it ***tables*** outside of all your functions. Then in the `drawTables` function simply push the new table onto this array:

```
 var table = new Tabulator //... insert rest of table definition

 tables.push(table); //push table to array of tables.
```

Then when you need to redraw all the tables, simply iterate through the array and call the redraw function on each one:

```
tables.forEach(function(table){
    table.redraw();
});
```